# Linux Plymouth splash screen works only recovery mode

Tags: boot, grub2, plymouth

We have a Jetway motherboard (embedded PC), and we've installed a minimal ubuntu 14.04 on it. After that we modified the system following these instructions:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-the-Big-and-Ugly-Plymouth-Logo-in-Ubuntu-10-04-140810.shtml

After reboot, the screen is unreadable, there is no splash screen (only an ugly white background, with some black lines), but if we reboot the system during the boot process, the grub appears, and the plymouth spash screen works. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the incorrect driver. Uvesafb dont supports monitor mirroring.